# Embed PHP into HTML

Tags: php, html, echo

I'm trying to use PHP to print out  values for my select statements but I can't get it to work. I've even tried just to print something out in my html with php, but i can't even seem to do that. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
    <?php echo "register Student:"; ?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you save your file as .php *not* .html.

**myfile.php:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
    <?php echo "register Student:"; ?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

You will also need to run this file on a server that has php installed. It won't run directly in the browser like an .html file will.

Answer (score 1):

Keep these things in mind.

1. Your file name should always end with .php extension not .htm or .html
2. You should always run file on localhost/ where you set up your environment
3. Please follow the standard of W3C Use a "li" in you "ul"

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Name your file **whatever.php**
Make sure it is *NOT* **whatever.html**

If that doesn't work, be sure to check whether or not you installed php. I suggest a local testing ground such as XAMPP. If you don't want to do that, upload it to a free or paid hosting service.